# Random access iterator: What am I missing?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, iterator

I have a simple array-based container and I want to make an iterator for it. My goal is to make std::sort work so I'm using random access iterator.

Iterator Class:

```cpp
class MyIterator: public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T> {
        friend class ArraySequence;
    private:
        T* pos;
        MyIterator(T* pos);
    public:
        MyIterator(const MyIterator &it);
        ~MyIterator();
    public:
        typename MyIterator::reference operator*() const;
        typename MyIterator::pointer operator->() const;
        typename MyIterator::reference operator[](const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const;
        MyIterator operator++(int);
        MyIterator& operator++();
        MyIterator operator--(int);
        MyIterator& operator--();
        MyIterator operator+(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const;
        MyIterator& operator+=(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n);
        MyIterator operator-(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const;
        MyIterator& operator-=(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n);
        bool operator!=(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator==(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator<(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator>(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator<=(const MyIterator& it) const;
        bool operator>=(const MyIterator& it) const;
    };
```

And it's methods:

```cpp
template <typename T>
ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::MyIterator(T* pos): pos(pos) {}

template <typename T>
ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::MyIterator(const MyIterator& it): pos(it.pos) {}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::reference ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator*() const {
    return *pos;
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::pointer ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator->() const {
    return pos;
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::reference ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator[](const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const {
    return *(pos + n);
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::MyIterator::operator++(int) {
    return MyIterator(pos++);
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator& ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::MyIterator::operator++() {
    ++pos;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::MyIterator::operator--(int) {
    return MyIterator(pos--);
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator& ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::MyIterator::operator--() {
    --pos;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator+(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const {
    return MyIterator(pos + n);
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator& ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator+=(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) {
    pos += n;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator& ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator-=(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) {
    pos -= n;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator-(const typename MyIterator::difference_type& n) const {
    return MyIterator(pos - n);
}

template <typename T>
bool ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator!=(const MyIterator& it) const {
    return pos != it.pos;
}

template <typename T>
bool ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator==(const MyIterator& it) const {
    return pos == it.pos;
}

template <typename T>
bool ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator<(const MyIterator& it) const {
    return pos < it.pos;
}

template <typename T>
bool ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator>(const MyIterator& it) const {
    return pos > it.pos;
}

template <typename T>
bool ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator<=(const MyIterator& it) const {
    return pos <= it.pos;
}

template <typename T>
bool ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator>=(const MyIterator& it) const {
    return pos >= it.pos;
}

template <typename T>
ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::~MyIterator() {}
```

When I try to run std::sort I get a lot of compiler errors such as "Invalid operands to binary expression ('ArraySequence::MyIterator' and 'ArraySequence::MyIterator')" on line "difference_type __len = __last - __first;". What am I missing here? What can be improved?

Comment: There is no `operator -` taking two iterators and returning a difference_type. That's the long and short of that error message. So... provide one ?

Comment: @WhozCraig how can I overload operator - like this? When I try to use it with the signature ```c++
difference_type operator- (MyIterator &it1, MyIterator&it2)
``` the compiler gives me an error message

Comment: @WhozCraig I overloaded it with right signature and everything now works. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot that you need to implement `operator -` for the iterators themselves.  Random access iterator support `it1 - it2` to get a distance between the two iterators.  You have `operator -` for the `difference_type`, but not for the iterator type itself.  You need to add an overload like:

```
template <typename T>
typename MyIterator::difference_type ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator::operator-(const typename ArraySequence<T>::MyIterator& n) const
{
    return pos - n.pos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've done this and now everything is working as intended!